# In Code By Zapier how to append a field to a constant URL?

Tags: zapier

In Code by Zapier how to append a field to a constant URL? I need the whole code block to insert since I don't know even how to make it output. In the form field above where the code is entered I entered an address. This is so the address can be found in google maps. Ideally I hope to send the street view image to email rather than having to click the link in email. Below is one variation of what I've tried. Thank you

```
let address = inputData.address;
var mylink = "https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/" + address;
output = mylink;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code will work, except for returning a `string` instead of an object type. Try this:

```js
const address = inputData.address;
const mylink = "https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/" + address;
return { result: mylink }
```

If that doesn't work, please update your question with info about what's not working.